# disnake bot status - streaming

Tags: python, бот, discord

Как я могу реализовать возможность сделать эту иконку статуса как 'стримит'

```
activity = disnake.Activity(status=disnake.Status.streaming, name="Вопросы? - SawaPlayGO#3481")
await bot.change_presence(activity=activity)
```

Это то что я пробовал, но иконка не менялась, не знаю в чём может быть проблема, даже при любом другом использовании статуса из всех возможных:

```
class Status(Enum):
    online = "online"
    offline = "offline"
    idle = "idle"
    dnd = "dnd"
    do_not_disturb = "dnd"
    invisible = "invisible"
    streaming = "streaming"

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.value
```

я получал только статус 'online'.

[image: Показывает статус 'online']

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, как конкретно в disnake, но в discord py реализовал таким образом:

```
activity = discord.Streaming(name="!help", url="ВАША_ССЫЛКА")

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents, activity=activity, status=discord.Status.idle)
```

Answer (score 0):

вы забыли указать ссылку на канал

```
await bot.change_presence(activity=disnake.Streaming(name="Вопросы? - SawaPlayGO#3481", url=my_twitch_url))
```